# SQL computation between different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables like  follows：

**Table1**

```
BusinessId | CustomerName
```

**Table2**

```
BusinessId | Product Name
```

**Table3**

```
Product Name | Price
```

and I try to write a query which should count the total cost of every single customer：

```
SELECT Table1.CustomerName, COUNT(Table2.Product Name) * Table3.Price
FROM Table1, Table2, Table3
WHERE Table1.BusinessId = Table2.BusinessId AND
Table2.Product Name = Table3.Product Name
GROUP BY SERVICE_NAME
```

But that doesn't work:(

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The following should be much closer to what you need.  It as least fixes a bunch of problems in the query:

```
SELECT t1.CustomerName, SUM(t3.Price)  -- use the right aggregation function
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.BusinessId = t2.BusinessId JOIN   -- column name spelled correctly
     Table3 t3
     ON t1.BusinessId = t2.BusinessId AND
        t2.ProductName = t3.ProductName  -- if the column has a space, you need to escape it
GROUP BY t1.CustomerName  -- aggregate by the right column
```

Answer (score -1):

**COUNT(Table2.Product Name)**

no allowed space here

yor query may look as

```
SELECT Table1.CustomerName, COUNT(Table2.ProductName) * Table3.Price
FROM Table1, Table2, Table3
WHERE Table1.BusinessId = Table2.BusinessId AND
Table2.ProductName = Table3.ProductName
GROUP BY Table1.CustomerName,Table3.Price
```